# AWS Service Communication within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

I am trying to figure out how communication between AWS services within a VPC is secured and encrypted.

For example, if my ECS container pulls an image from ECR, is the traffic encrypted in-transit? Or if I am taking a manual snapshot of my RDS database, is the traffic between S3 and RDS to transfer the snapshot encrypted?

My question might be a bit naive, but I've so far been unable to find any information on this.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer an encrypted snapshot between Amazon S3 and Amazon RDS, you can utilize AWS Key Management Service (KMS) for encryption key management and protection.
Make sure the following requirements are already fulfilled:

1. Encryption is enabled on your RDS instance. This is mandatory before creating an RDS snapshot. You can enable encryption at rest during the creation of a new RDS instance or modify an existing instance to enable encryption (Please refer to [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html) for more details). When enabling encryption at rest for RDS, you can use either the default AWS managed keys or create a custom encryption key using AWS KMS.
2. After enabling encryption at rest, take a snapshot of your RDS instance. The snapshot will contain the encrypted data, and AWS KMS will manage the encryption key used for encrypting the data.

By utilizing AWS KMS and enabling encryption at rest for both RDS and S3, you ensure that the data transferred between S3 and RDS is encrypted and secure.

I trust this answer provides you with insights into AWS RDS and S3 encryption.